# Java EE Security

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ws-security

I'm an iOS developer and I need to develop a web service, because the iOS App needs to retrieve some information from a database stored in a server.

I want to develop this web service using Java EE, but I would like to have some information about the security of Java EE, because I need to ensure the security of data stored into the database on the server.

Do you have some book or great tutorial to recommend about Java EE security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the link of Java EE security official tutorial :
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html

And this is the link of Java EE web service official tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html

Remember that netbeans will help you a lot when developing web services.

Some tutorials with netbeans :

- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html
- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws.html

and this is REST web service tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very good material! I have another small question...How do you evaluete the Java EE security in genarl? The Javva EE distribution is it a good choice? Thankyou

Comment: Depends on your requirements, if it did not satisfy you, you can have a look at Apache Shiro that has a better security model.

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could _maybe_ be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).